# PostMessage is not received when the window / tab is not active

Tags: javascript, typescript, iframe, postmessage

My iframe fires a postMessage but if the tab is not active it does not get received and only gets received when the tab is active again.

What is the reason behind this and how can I receive the message even when the tab is inactive? Is it even possible?

Comment: What would you do with the message when the tab is inactive? It's indeed a feature that background tabs are first throttled, then deactivated, in order to save battery etc.

Comment: I need to render a component on my screen. It should work in the background even when the tab is not visible. How can i do that?

Comment: How is the tab going to render anything if it's in the background?

Comment: So here is the thing : lets say i create a request like an api call and then i switch my tabs and i come back to the tab after sometime and i want it to have rendered there.

Comment: I want to be able to receive the post message from the iframe even if the tab is hidden.

Comment: Even we I'm looking for this, but seems tricky at the moment due to sleeping tabs https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/articles/sleeping-tabs-faq/m-p/1705434